# DataGridView: Copy Insert specific Column to another DGV

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have two datagridviews (dgv) with two separates datasource, the first dgv  displays data for year N and the second one data for year N-1( along with other information: client, product, etc..same columns and same information for both dgvs except for the amount).
In order to compute some statistical variables I need to copy column “amount”  from dgv 2 and to insert it into dgv 1. 
The idea is to get on dgv with data from year N and year N-1 
Any idea how to do that, Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Windows Forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
// create a new column named Amount in your dgv at specified index (index 0 in my case)
int newColumnIndex = 0;
dgv2.Columns.Insert(newColumnIndex , new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "Amount" });
// get an index of the Amount column in your other dgv
var index = dgv1.Columns["Amount"].Index;
// copy all items from dgv1 in that column to new column in dgv2
for (int i = 0; i < dgv1.Rows.Count; i++)
    dgv2.Rows[i].Cells[newColumnIndex].Value = dgv1.Rows[i].Cells[index].Value;
```